# Infinite loop or no action when binding <<ListboxSelect>>

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter, listbox, infinite-loop

I am trying to use changes in the selection of a tkinter Listbox to plot on a matplotlib figure. I have bound ListboxSelect to a callback function that should grab the rows selected in the Listbox. It then takes the row information and plots it in an already existing matplotlib plot. My problem is that, depending if the last line of the callback function is commented out, the callback function infinitely loops or only triggers once despite changes to the Listbox selection. How do I get it to only perform the callback function one time per change of the Listbox selection and then do it every time there is a change?

```
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

root = Tk()
root.title('Plotting Tool')
root.minsize(640,480)

scheduleWindow = Toplevel()
scheduleWindow.title('Schedule')
scheduleWindow.geometry("%dx%d%+d%+d" % (0, 400, 0, 100))

scheduleList = Listbox(scheduleWindow, selectmode = EXTENDED)

x = []

for i in range(0,21):
    scheduleList.insert(END, i)
    x.append(i)

scheduleList.pack(expand=True, fill = Y)

fig = plt.figure(tight_layout=True)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, autoscale_on = True)
ax.set_xlim(0,20)

y = [0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,987,1597,2584,4181,6765]

ax.plot(x,y)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side = TOP, fill = BOTH, expand = True)
canvas.show()

def grayzone():
    print(scheduleList.curselection())
    try:
        gray
    except:
        pass
    else:
        #clearing function to be added later

    if scheduleList.curselection() == ():
        gray = ax.axvspan( 0, 0,ymin=0, ymax=1,facecolor='gray',alpha=0.25)

    else:
        gray = ax.axvspan( scheduleList.curselection()[0], scheduleList.curselection()[-1],ymin=0, ymax=1,facecolor='gray',alpha=0.25)

    canvas.show()
    #scheduleList.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', grayzone())

scheduleList.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', grayzone())
```

Answer (score 2):

You are doing the binding incorrectly, and more than you need. You only need to add the binding once, and you need to give the binding a *reference* to a function. Instead, you are *calling* the function from inside `grayzone`, and then giving the results of that to the binding. That is why you are getting recursion problems: `grayzone` is calling `grayzone`.

Do it like this outside of `grayzone`, and remove the one that is inside `grayzone`:

```
scheduleList.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', grayzone)
```

Note the absence of the trailing parenthesis.

Also, be aware that when an event triggers, tkinter will always pass an event object to the callback. You'll need to modify `grayzone` to accept that. Since you don't actually use the event object and you want to be able to call the function outside of the callback, you can make it optional:

```
def grayzone(event=None):
    ...
```

Comment: The problem I have found with doing that is I get this error.

     TypeError: grayzone() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: @Tikkanen: correct: when an event triggers, it passes an event object along to the called function. You'll need to modify `grayzone` to accept that parameter. I'll update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Excellent. Looks like I need to read a little more into called functions. Thank you.